# Getting this error trying to add icons: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'IconData' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add icons dynamically to a menu. I have a class where I have an IconData attribute, a list with my IconData elements, and a widget where I add the Icons.

This is the code that is producing the error:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Icon(category.iconLocation)
),
```

Here is my list:

```
static const _icons = <IconData>[
    Icons.sim_card,
    Icons.settings_input_antenna,
    Icons.network_check,
    Icons.shopping_cart,
    Icons.shop,
    Icons.people
  ];
```

This is my category class:

```
class Category {
  final String name;
  final ColorSwatch color;
  final List<Servicio> units;
  final IconData iconLocation;
}
```

This is how I build my categories:

```
var category = Category(
        name: key,
        units: units,
        color: _baseColors[categoryIndex],
        iconLocation: _icons[categoryIndex],
      );
```

I know the error says I am giving a String instead of an IconData but I know my variable is indeed an IconData.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line specifically is throwing the error? And what is the full text of the error?

Comment: It is category.iconLocation inside of Icon. It is the first snippet of code inside a Padding. The error is this: The following _TypeError was thrown building CategoryTile(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#78c68]]):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'IconData' of 'function result'

Comment: If I paste this code in DartPad, I get the expected result of an icon with valid `IconData`. Therefore, your error is not in this code.

Comment: It seems the error originates when building the widget that has the icons:
return CategoryTile(
            category: _categories[index],
            onTap: _onCategoryTap,
          );

Answer (score 0):

if yours is a runtime error and not compile error, your var categoryIndex value is over the number of icons stored _icons list. and the String may be the exception message throw from List class.

Comment: Error messages don't get returned as strings from list accessors. They are thrown as errors.